# e.preventDefault() not working on onClick/onFocus event with an input

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Trying to prevent the default behavior of clicking and focusing on an input. I understand that I can use CSS to prevent this (pointer-events: none). I am eventually trying to prevent clicking on input at certain caret positions.

Is there an explanation as to why `e.preventDefault()` isn't working in this situation?

```js
import React from "react";

function InputText() {

  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <input onClick={handleClick}></input>
  );
}

export default InputText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use the attribute `Disable` of input to prevent users from clicking and focusing. I think onclick just working well on stuff like buttons.